# Advertise service with Bonjour on Windows

Tags: windows, bonjour

I'm developping a remote control on iPhone for Mac OS and Windows. I use Bonjour framework and it's working well on Mac OS. I can see on my iPhone the different Mac devices which have my server.

I would like to do the same thing on Windows with language C or C#.
I haver wrote a piece of code it does'nt work : my iPhone does'nt see the service.
Here's a line of code that can be wrong I think :

```
if(DNSServiceRegister(&service, 0, 0, HostName, "_esiearemote._tcp.", "", NULL,htonl(PORT), 0, NULL, reg_reply, NULL)!=kDNSServiceErr_NoError)
```

Have you got an idea ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you compiling it against `dnssd.dll`?

Have you tried using `C:\Windows\system32\dns-sd.exe` instead? At least as a debugging tool?

Is `mDNSResponder` (the Bonjour Service) running? Many people disable it.

Also the problem could be between your PC and the iPhone, check if the service is advertised correctly on your PC, with **Safari**, the **BonjourFoxy Firefox Extension** or the **Bonjour SDK**

I also posted a couple of links to Apple documentation (the **dns-sd** and **dnssd.dll/dylib** manpages) [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463218/how-to-advertise-a-bonjour-service-in-visual-c/3988696#3988696).