# How to advertise a Bonjour Service in Visual C++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, bonjour, zeroconf

I'm trying to figure out if this is even possible, but what's the simplest way of advertising a Bonjour service through Visual C++?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the *DNS Service Discovery* client: **dns-sd**.

*Windows Bonjour Installer* puts it in `C:\Windows\system32\dns-sd.exe`

Its *synopsis* is:

```
 dns-sd -R name type domain port [key=value ...]

 dns-sd -B type domain

 dns-sd -L name type domain
```

There **isn't any easy way to find indepth Bonjour windows documentation**, (and it's a serious shame) but here's the manpage for its mac equivalent:
[http://developer.apple.com/.../dns-sd.1.html](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dns-sd.1.html)

There is also `C:\Windows\system32\dnssd.dll` whose API, *I unfortunately have to suppose*, conforms to this document:
[http://developer.apple.com/.../dns_sd_h/](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/DNSServiceDiscovery_CRef/dns_sd_h/)

Comment: Update: one *atrocious* detail from documentation: «The dns-sd command is primarily intended for **interactive use**.  Because its **command-line arguments and output format are subject to change**, invoking it from a shell script will generally be **fragile** »

Answer (score 0):

This is rather old question... however as I had recently implemented Bonjour functionality in Windows for one project, have some insight into it. There is a Bonjour SDK for Windows from Apple developer site with examples in C, C#, etc. In C examples folder there is a complete source for dns-sd client which you can then use to build your own client (for registering services, names, etc.). As that is C, you can then easily pack this functionality as dll and then allow and other languages to use it (for example, C#).

[Bonjour SDK for Windows @ developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=Bonjour%20SDK%20for%20Windows)